# Does wprintf cause "conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value(s)" in valgrind?

Tags: c, valgrind

I'm trying to code the function solving the following problem (which is irrellevant, I'm describing it in order to describe the code that follows):

Given a word and a rule in form: "lhs->rhs" where word = lhs ^ suffix, output rhs ^ suffix, so for example:

If a word is "input" and a rule is "in->out" the function would return the word "output", or NULL if the rule cannot be used for the word.

There is a twist though: "lhs" might also contain digit variables (in addition to letters), e. g. "01->10", in this case, that rule would convert "niput" to "input" when used on "niput" (so digits correspond to letters standing at certain positions).

Here's the code:

```
#include <wchar.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

#define MAX_WORD_SIZE 101

wchar_t *transform_by_rule(wchar_t *word, wchar_t *lhs, wchar_t *rhs)
{
    int i;
    long int wint;
    int lhs_len = wcslen(lhs);
    int rhs_len = wcslen(rhs);
    int word_len = wcslen(word);

    // Initial check - does lhs fit to word
    if (word_len < lhs_len)
        return NULL;
    for (i = 0; i < lhs_len; i++)
    {
        if (iswdigit(lhs[i]))
            continue;
        else
        {
            if (lhs[i] != word[i])
                return NULL;
        }
    }

    wchar_t *result =
        malloc((rhs_len + 1) * sizeof(wchar_t));
    wchar_t int_wchar_map[10];
    for (i = 0; i < lhs_len; i++)
    {
        if (iswdigit(lhs[i]))
        {
            wint = lhs[i] - L'0';
            int_wchar_map[wint] = word[i];
        }
    }
    for (i = 0; i < rhs_len; i++)
    {
        if (iswdigit(rhs[i]))
        {
            wint = rhs[i] - L'0';
            result[i] = int_wchar_map[wint];
        }
        else
        {
            result[i] = rhs[i];
        }
    }
    return result;
}


int main()
{
    wchar_t word[MAX_WORD_SIZE];
    wchar_t lhs[MAX_WORD_SIZE];
    wchar_t rhs[MAX_WORD_SIZE];
    wscanf(L"%ls", word);
    wscanf(L"%ls", lhs);
    wscanf(L"%ls", rhs);
    wchar_t *result = transform_by_rule(word, lhs, rhs);
    if (result != NULL)
    {
        wprintf(L"%ls\n", result); // line 67
        free(result);
    }
    else
    {
        puts("Rule doesn't fit to word.");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Here's the problem. When run under valgrind for input "a" (word), "a" (lhs), "b" (rhs), the valgrind outputs error:

```
==6094== Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value(s)
==6094==    at 0x4C30E19: wcslen (in /usr/lib64/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==6094==    by 0x4E8C3F6: vfwprintf (in /usr/lib64/libc-2.20.so)
==6094==    by 0x4EA7448: wprintf (in /usr/lib64/libc-2.20.so)
==6094==    by 0x4009AA: main (main.c:67)
```

I don't see any problem with my code. Is this a problem with wprintf()?

Comment: often times this warning can be solved by using calloc() instead

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`result` is not zero-terminated before returning from `transform_by_rule()`. Thus, when calling `wprintf()` on its return value, `wprintf()` may read out-of-bound since it may not encounter terminating wide character within the allocated memory block.

Use `wchar_t *result = calloc(rhs_len + 1, sizeof(wchar_t));`, and you get correctly terminated string automatically if you are sure that you don't write over boundary inside `transform_by_rule()`.